# Looking for a synonym for the verb break

Tags: meaning, verbs, synonyms

In the sentence below, are the verbs "to break" and "to enter in" synonyms?

> Issue #7 breaks new ground that was untouched by the video game.

[Source](http://batman-news.com/2013/08/01/injustice-gods-among-us-7-review/).

Comment: No.  "Break new ground " is a metaphor -- it implies plowing an unplowed field (as a farmer might).  The meaning it to enter some new field of endeavor that was previously not "plowed" by anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "enter" is more broadly used as a "transitive verb" that doesn't require a preposition.

"To [break new ground](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/break-new-ground)" means "to enter [***uncharted territory***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/uncharted-territory-waters)" which means:

> an activity or subject that people do not know anything about or have
>   not experienced before: 'Genetic engineers are 
>   entering uncharted territory

[Macmillan Online Dictionary]
'.